# MiniZinc: zipping pairs of non-zero elements in a list

Tags: arrays, minizinc

I have a situation where I am modelling an array `S` that contains a set of values (a schedule) from a predefined domain `1..t`, plus `0`, which is a special value for "not there/not used".

I now want to post a constraint to sum a cost function, represented as a 2D array `C`, for the list `S'`, holding every non-zero element of `S` in the same order, like so:

`constraint x = sum([C[S'[d], S'[d + 1]] | d in 1..max - 1])`

However, this cannot be easily done. Things I have tried:

- Using the function form of `roots` to get the set of indices to `S` whose data is non-zero. The problem with that solution is:

  - the result is a set, and so cannot be zipped into pairs or easily cast to a list, even though I know their number from provided instance data.
  - roots seems to require that all values participate in the array, whereas I would like only to have the full domain except 0.
- Using a list comprehension (e.g. `[S[i] | i in 1..max where S[i] != 0]`) to select only the elements whose values are non-zero: this also doesn't work, as the `where` clause on the list comprehension causes the list to be of type `opt`, and also having the wrong number of elements (where I presume some of them will be `<>`), essentially reducing the problem of filtering zeroes to the same problem again with `<>`:s.
- Treating the cost function as a DFA and 0 values as self-loops: this does not (in any way I can identify) allow for counting; only validating transitions, which I don't care about.

What I would really like here is either `filter` or `zip`, which could both easily solve my problem, but I presume that there is some sort of standard solution that I'm missing. Otherwise, I would have to re-design the model.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to solve your problem by using a recursive function that calculates the costs by iterating over the indices of your array `S`. I illustrate the function `calculate_cost()` below in a small example:

```
int: t = 10; int: N = 5;

% cost array
array[1..t,1..t] of int: C = array2d(1..t,1..t,[ i | i in 1..t, j in 1..t]);

% variables
array[1..N] of var 0..t: S;
var 0..1000: x;

% constraints
constraint S[1] = 4; % setting some arbitrary values
constraint S[2] = 7;
constraint S[3] = 0;
constraint S[4] = 6;

constraint x =  calculate_cost(1,2);

function var int: calculate_cost(int: index1, int:index2) =
  if index1 > N then 0 
  elseif index2 > N then 0
  else 
    let {
       var bool: value_at_index1_is_zero = S[index1] == 0;
       var bool: value_at_index2_is_zero = S[index2] == 0;
    }
    in 
      if value_at_index1_is_zero 
         then calculate_cost(index1+1, index1+2)
      elseif value_at_index2_is_zero 
         then calculate_cost(index1, index2 + 1) 
      else 
        C[S[index1],S[index2]] + calculate_cost(index2, index2+1)   
      endif
  endif;

solve satisfy;
```

This example has `S = [4, 7, 0, 6, 0]` and calculates costs `x = C[4,7] + C[7,6] = 4 + 7 = 11`.

In the function `calculate_cost()`, I recursively calculate the sum by skipping indices that have a zero value in `S`. In the first few lines, I check if the indices are out of bounds and return 0 in that case (base case of the recursion). Then I create two local  variables that are `true` if the value at `S[index]` is zero for `index`. Then, if case one of those cases are true, I ignore those indices, and recursively call the function again, and increase/adapt the respective index in the recursive call.

This works, but is probably not a very nice way of solving this issue because it introduces a lot of auxiliary variables in the FlatZinc model, so it might still be better to reformulate the problem.

Comment: That's very nice thank you! I'll run it against a modified model and see how bad those extra variables are comparatively speaking, because any other soliton probably also introduces a number of redundant decision variables.